# Ignore raising exception to the caller in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pep

How can I ignore a certain exception to be raised to the caller in python 3?

**Example:**

```
def do_something():
    try:
        statement1
        statement2
    except Exception as e:
        # ignore the exception
        logging.warning("this is normal, exception is ignored")


try:
    do_something()
except Exception as e:
    # this is unexpected control flow, the first exception is already ignored !! 
    logging.error("unexpected error")
    logging.error(e)  # prints None
```

I found someone mentioned that "*Because of the last thrown exception being remembered in Python, some of the objects involved in the exception-throwing statement are being kept live indefinitely*" and then mentioned to use "sys.exc_clear()" in this case which is not available anymore in python 3. Any clue how can I completely ignore the exception in python3?

Comment: If you see something where the outer `except` block is being triggered in your actual program, you have some other issue that isn't reflected in your question. The code structure in your question should never trigger the outer `except` block.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do this in Python `3`, `sys.exc_clear()` was removed because Python doesn't store the last raised exception internally as it did in Python 2:

For example, in Python 2, the exception is still kept alive when inside a function:

```
def foo():
    try:
        raise ValueError()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    import sys; print(sys.exc_info())
```

Calling `foo` now shows the exception is kept:

```
foo()
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError(), <traceback object at 0x7f45c57fc560>)
```

You need to call `sys.exc_clear()` in order to clear the `Exception` raised.

In Python 3, on the contrary:

```
def foo():
    try:
        raise ValueError()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    import sys; print(sys.exc_info())
```

Calling the same function:

```
foo()    
(None, None, None)
```